# Сайт занимает не всю ширину экрана

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

```
`https://codepen.io/alexxandmerniy/pen/BaNZoxN`
```

Суть в том что инспектор говорит что html - 100% но тем не менее всю ширину экрана не занимает, получаеться вот что:[image: Изображение проблемы]. Очень прошу ткнуть на ошибку, сайт нужно быстрее доделывать, а я в этом деле новичок. Спасибо, заранее

Comment: Подскажите, как можно воспроизвести Вашу проблему? Проверил на `codepen`, не смог воспроизвести то, что на скриншоте. Ширина всегда занимает доступное пространство.

Comment: Советую почистить кеши браузера...похоже у вас не актуальные стили..у меня все ок..проверил в ff,chrome

Answer (score 0):

кроме как HTML необходимо ещё посмотреть тег body ну или глубже по дереву
У Вас блок родитель ограничен шириной но вот какой непонятно, был бы код
смотрите блоки начиная с родтелей и идите по чучуть к детям  body>section,header,footer,wrapper,container>div>div>div
 уодного из них будет фиксорованя ширина

```
.style{
    width:100%
     }
```

лучше не использовать потому как блочный елемент автоматически тянеться на всю длинну родителя, данная конструкция для блочного елемента имеет смысл только если раньше было указано по другому.
посмотрите можте body ограничили
а ещ' лучше код кинуть сюда чтоб можно было понять что да как, по ссылке что Вы предоставили вроде всё ок